# ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the UsersService (?)

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

i'm playing around with nest a bit and i'm trying to build a module that i can publish on my private repo so that i can reuse it whenever i need it.

but i encounter this error:

```
ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the UserRepository (?). Please make sure that the argument DataSource at index [0] is available in the TypeOrmModule context.

Potential solutions:
- Is TypeOrmModule a valid NestJS module?
- If DataSource is a provider, is it part of the current TypeOrmModule?
- If DataSource is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within TypeOrmModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing DataSource */ ]
  })
```

i've built the module using nest build and then npm link it to the main project.

if the module is inside the main project it works, the problem arise when it's in another repo.

here is my app.module

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { UsersModule, User } from '@MY-PACKAGE-LINKED/user';

@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      useFactory: () => ({
        type: 'mysql',
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 3306,
        username: 'root',
        password: 'root',
        database: 'test',
        entities: [User],
        synchronize: true,
      }),
    }),
    UsersModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

here's my users.module

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { UsersController } from './users.controller';
import { UsersService } from './users.service';
import { User } from './entities/user.entity';
import { UserRepository } from './users.repository';
@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([User])],
  controllers: [UsersController],
  providers: [UserRepository, UsersService],
})
export class UsersModule { }
```

what i thought was passing in the app.module in the providers array the UsersService, like so

```
...
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService, UsersService],
})
...
```

but by doing so i get another error (a different one, we are going places!)

```
ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the UsersService (?). Please make sure that the argument UserRepository at index [0] is available in the AppModule context.

Potential solutions:
- Is AppModule a valid NestJS module?
- If UserRepository is a provider, is it part of the current AppModule?
- If UserRepository is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within AppModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing UserRepository */ ]
  })
```

what am i doing wrong here? i feel like it's a dumb thing, because it works if the module is on the same project, it only brakes when i try to have it another repo and link it

edit:

users.service

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { User } from './entities/user.entity';
import { CreateUserParams } from './utils/types/types';

@Injectable()
export class UsersService {
    constructor(@InjectRepository(User) private userRepository: Repository<User>) { }

    async findOne(username: string): Promise<User | undefined> {
        return this.userRepository.findOne({ where: { username } });
    }

    async findAll(): Promise<User[]> {
        return this.userRepository.find();
    }

    createUser(userDetails: CreateUserParams) {
        const newUser = this.userRepository.create({ ...userDetails, createdAt: new Date() });
        return this.userRepository.save(newUser);
    }
}
```

edit2: the problem seems to be that the connection does not get shared, and by doing so this problem occurs...

i'm trying to solve it, i hope it will work :p

SOLVED!

the problem is npm link...

i used https://github.com/wclr/yalc and everything works!!

Comment: Some of the arguments in the constructor of your UsersService are not resolvable. Can you show us the UsersService? If the UserRepository is injected and not resolvable, can you make sure that the UserRepository is marked as `Injectable`?

Comment: @Silvermind i edited the question with the user service

Comment: I'm not familiar with nestjs, but I find this odd: `UserRepository` vs `Repository<User>`. Are they the same and if so, why do they have different names. Are they both injectable. Are you missing a setup for the generic type. Perhaps the `User` token has not been registered yet in this piece of code: `@InjectRepository(User)`

Comment: Please do **not** edit your question to include the solution; post a self-answer instead: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution was easy.

the problem was npm link.

i used https://github.com/wclr/yalc and everything works!!